# Position absolute div not appearing in front of overflow-y scroll content

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-position

Basically, I need the "modal" div to fill the height/width of the `.container` div no matter where you scroll in the div. For some reason, the `.modal` div keeps appearing in a stack with the `.inner-wrapper` div even though it is position absolute.

Why does it not fill the parent `.container` div?

I'd like to avoid JS, if possible.

I've tried playing with the `position` properties on all the divs involved. I've also tried playing with the translate property. I was thinking that `display: flex` may have something to do with this too, but was proven wrong. My guess is that this issue is related to the `overflow-y: scroll`.

```js
$(".open-btn").click(function() {
  $(".modal").toggle();
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.inner-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  background: rgba(34, 34, 12, 0.3);
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.open-btn {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="modal"></div>
  <div class="inner-wrapper">
    <button class="open-btn">Open</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

See Codepen link below for context:
https://codepen.io/nss5161/pen/abaPZvy?editors=1100

[Position on Scroll Div Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m67cl.png)
[Multiple Position on Scroll Div Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXAfP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**-- Edited --**

I hope that's what you need.

```js
$(".open-btn").click(function() {
  $(".modal").toggle();
});
```

```css
.main {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.inner-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  background: rgba(34, 34, 12, 0.3);
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.open-btn {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
}

.modal {
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 3%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="modal"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="inner-wrapper">
      <button class="open-btn">Open</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: - This is close, however, when I scroll to the bottom and click the "open" button, the ".modal" div does not appear to the center of the ".container" div. Your solution places the ".modal" div in the center of the ".inner-wrapper" div. I need the ".modal" div to appear in the center of the ".container" div, no matter where I am at in the vertical scroll.

Comment: I have added a new image link (diagram) to the question post. See link "Multiple Position on Scroll Div Diagram" above for more context.

Comment: I edited the code, and I hope I understood what you wanted.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was looking for. I just had to adjust a few things to get it exact, but your answer provided me the solution I was looking for. Thanks!! Updated Codepen Link: [Solution Edited](https://codepen.io/nss5161/pen/XWPOPox?editors=1100)

Answer (score 0):

it will not work in that context. You need to add an inner container as `position: absolute` will position to the relative parents' scroll-viewport as that is the actual parent's boundary.

Add a simple wrapper inside the container to work as a relative parent:

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.inner-container {
  position: relative;
}

.inner-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  background: rgba(34, 34, 12, 0.3);
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.open-btn {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
}

.modal {
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div class="modal"></div>
    <div class="inner-wrapper">
      <button class="open-btn">Open</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi tacoshy. Thanks for the quick response. This isn't quite what I'm looking for. It was really tough for me to explain in text what I was looking for, so this ones on me. I've edited my post above to include the jQuery line from the Codepen link. I have also attached a screenshot to better explain (visually) what I'm looking for. See link in post "Position on Scroll Div Diagram":

Comment: Basically, it should be filling the parent ".container" div (which is only 300x300) and not the entire ".inner-wrapper".

Comment: I have added a new image link (diagram) to the question post. See link "Multiple Position on Scroll Div Diagram" above for more context.

Answer (score 0):

is it what you expect?

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.inner-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  background: rgba(34, 34, 12, 0.3);
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: end;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.open-btn {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  align-self: end;
}

.modal {
  width: 90%;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  background: green;
  position: sticky;
  left: 15px;
  top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="modal"></div>
  <div class="inner-wrapper">
    <button class="open-btn">Open</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Milad. Thanks for the quick response. This isn't quite what I'm looking for. It was really tough for me to explain in text what I was looking for, so this ones on me. I've edited my post above to include the jQuery line from the Codepen link. I have also attached a screenshot to better explain (visually) what I'm looking for. See link in post "Position on Scroll Div Diagram":

Comment: Hi @MidnightFlashMoonLaser, try `position: sticky;`
also I edit the answer too. you can check the code too.

Comment: Yes, this is pretty much there! Looks like it is still acknowledging the height of the ".modal" div. If you scroll to the top, there is an empty space. I can prob remove this by translating the ".inner-wrapper" div or adjusting negative margin or position, but I'm still finding it hard to understand why adjusting the "position" attribute doesn't ignore relative stack???

Comment: I have added a new image link (diagram) to the question post. See link "Multiple Position on Scroll Div Diagram" above for more context.